# In TFS Web Portal-using Agent Pool- created a New Agent - its not showing in TFS Server (XAML Build Configuration)

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, build, tfs-2015

I have create a New Agent, using TFS Web Portal-using Agent Pool- its not showing in TFS Server (XAML Build Configuration)

How to get in in Build Definition.

Answer (score 1):

The new build system in the TFS/VSTS web portal is a complete different from the previous XAML build. They are totally separate.

To use new build system, you need to go to TFS web access--Build tab, and create new build process template.

If you want to use old XAML build, you still need to configure build controller and build agent in traditional way.